# JavaScript generate array of strings with inline solution

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

There simple code:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    arr.push("some string with iterating value "+i);
}
```

I wonder if there is a one-line solution in which I enter the string and the maximum value and get an array of generated lines.

Comment: You want an array of strings in a one liner?

Comment: Let's say I have string: "some string %d" (%d is example). And maximum value: 2. I want to get array: ["some string 1", "some string 2"]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this, if the input is 5, you can have it as N and get the input from user

**DEMO**

```js
var result = Array.from(new Array(5),(val,index)=> "some string " + index );
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
const newArray = [...Array(10)].map((_, i) => `some string with iterating value ${i}`)
console.log(newArray)
```

You can use a spread operator and create a new array of the length you require, loop (`map`) over it and return the string. This will create a new array of the length (10) with the string you want in it.

Answer (score 1):

How about making it a reusable function? E.g.

```js
// Replaces '{i}' with the index number
var generateStringArray = (length, string) => Array.from(new Array(length), (val, index) => string.replace('{i}', index))

console.log(generateStringArray(6, "some string {i}"));
```

Comment: Good idea to make it a re-usable function, but then it is altogether too long to put on one line

Comment: It will be good if you can add some placeholder, like ${i} in previous answer.

Comment: var generateStringArray = (length, string) => Array.from(new Array(length), (val, index) =>  string.replace("{i}", index));

console.log(generateStringArray(6, "some string {i}"));

Comment: Updated the snippet :)